# How to split a string into individual chars in smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

I have a string that looks like: '1 3 4 5 7 8'

How would I iterate through it to split it into a chars so that for each char I can perform a function?

so my code looks like this:

```
| tempSet1Values tempSet2Values setConcat |
tempSet1Values := '1 2 3'.
tempSet2Values := '4 5 6'.
setConcat := tempSet1Values , ' ' , tempSet2Values
```

I want to separate each of the numbers in setConcat and add each number one at a time to another method. Sorry if I am not as helpful, I am new to Smalltalk.

Comment: It seems it should be `tempSet2Values := '4 5 6'`

Comment: sorry about that. My mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Smalltalks support the `#findTokens:` message on `String`s:

```
'1 2 3' findTokens: ' '. "-> anOrderedCollection('1', '2', '3')"
```

where the argument can also be multiple delimiters in the string, like `'.,;:'`.

Depending on dialect, it may be that `#findTokens:` does *not* take a `String` but a `Character`:

```
'1 2 3' findTokens: $ . "note the space" "-> anOrderedCollection('1', '2', '3')
```

Also, you probably do want to do the splitting before concatenation:

```
 | tempSetValues1 tempSetValues2 |
 tempSetValues1 := '1 2 3'.
 tempSetValues2 := '3 4 5'.
 (tempSetValues1 findTokens: ' '), (tempSetValues2 findTokens: ' ').
```

This can be generalized as the number of individual input strings gets larger.

Answer (score 1):

[This rosetta code sample looks to do what you are looking for](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string#Smalltalk)

```
|array |
array := 'Hello,How,Are,You,Today' subStrings: $,.
array fold: [:concatenation :string | concatenation, '.', string ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! so would that separate by space though? I tried doing a do block but that didn't work.

Comment: My Smalltalk's a *little* rusty, but that looks to me like it should change `Hello,How,Are,You,Today` to `Hello.How.Are.You.Today`. That is, break into sub-strings using `,` as a delimiter, then put the pieces back together, separated by `.` instead.

Comment: hmmm...but if I wanted my string to stay separated, would I still use a array fold?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious possibility would be to write a loop that steps through the characters of the string.

```
|input |
1 to: input size do:
    [ :index |
        "here `input at: index` is the current character of the string"
    ]
```

There are quite a few more possibilities though.

Answer (score 0):

```
'1 3 4 5 7 8'
inject: ''
into: [:str :each |
    (each sameAs: Character space)
        ifFalse: [
            Transcript show: each; cr ]].
```

This outputs a string one character at a time. Test this using a transcript window (Menu -> Tools -> Transcript). Replace the transcript call with the method of your choice.